# How do I correctly use the ansible hostname module?

Tags: bash, ansible, virtual-machine, system-administration

I am trying to use ansible to modify the hostnames of a dozen newly created Virtual Machines, and I am failing to understand how to loop correctly.

Here is the playbook I've written:

```
---
- hosts: k8s_kvm_vms
  tasks:
  - name: "update hostnames"
    hostname:
      name: "{{ item }}"
    with_items:
      - centos01
      - centos02
      ...
```

The result is that it updates each host with each hostname. So if I have 12 machines, each hostname would be "centos12" at the end of the playbook.

I expect this behavior to essentially produce the same result as:

```
num=0
for ip in ${list_of_ips[*]}; do 
    ssh $ip hostnamectl set-hostname centos${num}
    num=$((num+1))
done
```

If I were to write it myself in bash

[The answer on this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43144374/iterate-over-the-hostname-stored-in-var-files) leads me to believe I would have to include all of the IP addresses in my playbook. In my opinion, the advantage of scripting would be that I could have the same hostnames even if their IP changes (I just have to copy the ip addresses into /etc/ansible/hosts) which I could reuse with other playbooks. I have read the ansible page on the hostname module, but their example leads me to believe I would, instead of using a loop, have to define a task for each individual IP address. If this is the case, why use ansible over a bash script?

[ansible hostname module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/hostname_module.html)

Comment: Can you please show your inventory ? Did you name the machines after the IPs ?

Comment: It does work just like your bash script.  IF you loop through by IP, or original hostname (in your inventory) and set a variable for the new hostname in your inventory.  Like @Smily's answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can create a new variable for each of the servers in the inventory like

```
[k8s_kvm_vms]
server1 new_hostname=centos1
server2 new_hostname=centos2
```

Playbook:

```
---
- hosts: k8s_kvm_vms
  tasks:
  - name: "update hostnames"
    hostname:
      name: "{{ new_hostname }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to sudo to change the hostname thus you should add **"become: yes"**

```
---
- hosts: k8s_kvm_vms
  become: yes
  tasks:
  - name: "update hostnames"
    hostname:
      name: "{{ new_hostname }}"
```

Comment: OP's script doesn't lack sudo privileges - that much is clear by the fact that the hostname all end up as 'centos12'.

Comment: Not an answer.  And you're wrong.  the core issue is OP was renaming every host 12 times.